# Running sample Google Maven project in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, avro, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am brand new to GCP world. I am trying to run one of the pubsub examples (https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/src/main/java/pubsub/SubscribeWithAvroSchemaExample.java) in Google's Github repo on Cloud Shell.

Their documentation also has links to Cloud Shell (https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/tree/ff9c9c15a9efb10d5cbc9328c7a703a20b5d4b44#samples)

I am able to build on the cloud shell by running `mvn clean install`. But when I run that Java class SubscribeWithAvroSchemaExample.java (after filling in the project id and subscrption id), I get the below error

> satish_anupindi84@cloudshell:~$ cd '/home/satish_anupindi84' && env
> '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
> '-cp'
> '/home/satish_anupindi84/.theia/workspace-storage/e742f48ad7fde7236560e8cf9e48d278/redhat.java/jdt_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin'
> 'pubsub.SubscribeWithAvroSchemaExample' Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> ```
> at pubsub.SubscribeWithAvroSchemaExample.main(SubscribeWithAvroSchemaExample.java:39)
> ```

Would someone try this out and let me know what they get?

Ran it manually, and did not get any headway

> satish_anupindi84@cloudshell:~/cloudshell_open/java-pubsub-2$ cd
> samples/snippets/
> satish_anupindi84@cloudshell:~/cloudshell_open/java-pubsub-2/samples/snippets$
> env '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'
> '-Dfile-encoding=UTF-8' 'pubsub.SubscribeWithAvroSchemaExample' Error:
> Could not find or load main class
> pubsub.SubscribeWithAvroSchemaExample Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> pubsub.SubscribeWithAvroSchemaExample

Attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: The error suggests that the code did not compile correctly ("Unresolved compilation problem") when you ran `mvn install`. Rather than include what may be a lengthy set of logs, please review the output from that step and update your question with any errors. I assume you've followed the prereqs including creating a project, enabling billing, setting up pub/sub ...

Comment: Yes, I did. The Build was Successful. I don't know what else could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this issue. My guess is that when you ran `mvn clean install`, it also ran the tests included in the snippets. Some of those tests can take time and may fail, which can ruin the build process. If you simply want to test a snippet, then you can just skip those tests.

My suggestion is to add a flag to skip tests:

**UPDATE**: Check your current directory. Make sure to run this command at your `$HOME/cloudshell_open/java-pubsub-3/samples/snippets`.

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Afterwards, make sure the build returns success and then rerun the sample via Cloud Editor.

The steps I did:

1. Open a Terminal.
2. Clone repo to **$HOME** dir: `git clone https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub.git`
3. `cd java-pubsub/samples/snippets`
4. `mvn clean install -DskipTests` build result should look like this:

[image]

5. Open `samples/snippets` workspace at Cloud Shell Editor.
6. Go to your preferred class and click **Run** button near the main method. Right Click and Run should also work.

I was able to make it work properly. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I used `man clean install -DskipTests` as well. It completes successfully. But when I right click and run the class, it gives me a "Build failed, do you want to continue?" popup on the bottom right. I cannot check why it failed - even though running in cloud shell passed! Did you run it on cloud shell using the command you showed manually? It should run it when i right click and run, correct?

Comment: Please check edits, I wasn't able to run it manually as well.

Comment: @user2405589 I looked at your build result and I noticed that you're building the entire library instead of the snippets. Run the build command at `samples/snippets` directory and try again. Or follow the steps that I did. I updated my answer.

Comment: @user2405589 I ran the code by clicking the Run button just near the main method. Right click and Run should work as well. I also used `CTRL + ~` to open a terminal at the editor and ran the commands there.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why it didnt work when going to cloud shell directly from the github page. Somehow the classpath wasn't defined correctly then